# Extract code from method body and execute it inline using expressions?

Tags: .net, lambda, expression-trees

Take this code for example which creates a custom delegate that calls a method called `AddNumbers`:

```
public static int AddNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ParameterExpression
        arga = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int)),
        argb = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

    MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(typeof(Program_ModelBinding).GetMethod("AddNumbers"), arga, argb);

    var deli = Expression.Lambda(result, arga, argb).Compile() as Func<int, int, int>;

    Console.WriteLine(deli(2, 4));
}
```

That compiles to:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]>(
    System.Int32 $var1,
    System.Int32 $var2) {
    .Call ModelBinding.Program_ModelBinding.AddNumbers(
        $var1,
        $var2)
}
```

However, to reduce chattiness and keep the stack tidy, I would like to be able to inline the `AddNumbers` method so that its method body is compiled within the code itself as if I did this:

```
BinaryExpression result = Expression.Add(arga, argb);
```

That would compile to this:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32]>(
    System.Int32 $var1,
    System.Int32 $var2) {
    $var1 + $var2
}
```

I'll also note that I would prefer not to have to work off an object instance even if the method is non-static.  I just want to extract the method body and then use it inline within my code.

I somehow think the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace has the answer I am looking for, but I don't know which direction to proceed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that methods generated using `Expression`, `MethodBuilder`, `DynamicMethod` etc will never get inlined.  The best you can do is actually generate that statement in your expression and compile that but I guess that wouldn't give you what you want.

Comment: @jamespconnor Correct, that wouldn't work.  The idea is that, if I ever change the code in the concrete method, the generated code would pull in the new method body.  I don't want to have to duplicate logic in two places so that I'd also have to modify the expression code to match what the concrete method is doing.

Comment: Could you create the `Expression` as a `static` then use it in both places? e.g. `private static readonly Expression<Func<int, int, int>> AddNumbers = (a, b) => a + b;`

Comment: @jamespconnor No, because I don't want to have to write everything using expressions.  It seems to me that if the compiler can inline concrete methods during compilation, there'd be a way to do it explicitly using expressions.

Comment: What if you use @jamespconnor's idea and define the expression in one place, then have a method `InvokeAddNumbers` which calls `AddNumbers` in the background? You'd then use `InvokeAddNumbers` wherever you want to call directly, and you'd use the `AddNumbers` expression when building expressions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this.

The C# compiler compiles your method into IL and converting that back to expressions is possible, but complicated and the level of success can be variable. You might be able to use the code of an existing decompiler to help (for example [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) is open source) and there might even be a library that does this (the only thing I found is [this old library](https://github.com/ashmind/expressive)).

But my guess is that all this is not worth it just to "reduce chattiness and keep the stack tidy".

Answer (score 0):

One, simple minded method, is to programmatically disassemble the AddNumbers function, and then use that output to drive Reflection.Emit to create the inlined code on the fly.

However you probably want some way to have placeholders in your Main (or whatever method which will receive the inlined code) to hold the emitted code. In other words you probably don't want to emit all of Main, you want the compiler to create everything but the inline code for AddNumbers. (But you could apply the same decompilation/recompilation approach to the whole Main method).

A problem with that, though, is much space needs to be reserved? If the code you inline is as simple as AddNumbers, that's not much of a problem. You can replace the original method invocation with the inlined code because it'll be shorter. But if the code to inline is even moderately more complex than AddNumbers you'll need more space for the inlined code and a way to cause the compiler to leave enough space.

But as the inlined code gets longer the savings for inlining become smaller, so maybe you could just have a hard limit on the size of the code - any code to be inlined must be smaller than the limit.

I think to give a better answer you need to give more info on the problem:

Do you want the compiler generated code and inlined code to be mixed in a single method? Or will a separate, dynamically create, method work?

If it's the former will there be a single site to hold the inlined code? Or will there be more than one, but a fixed, smallish number of sites?

How complex (in number of IL instructions) do you anticipate the code to inline will be?

Is dynamically generated and compiled C# code an option? Depending on your answers to the other questions Reflection.Emit may not be a good choice - rather you may need the intelligence of a compiler.